# Example when the hypothesis of the implicit function theorem is false, but the conclusion is true.

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

I am wondering if there are any function(s) such that the conclusion of the implicit function theorem holds true, despite the function(s) not satisfying the conditions stated in the hypothesis.  For quick reference, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem.

I've thought about it for awhile, tried to play around with some possibilities, and have come up with none.  However, I believe I saw this question on an old exam.

Comment: That would not be, by definition, a counter-example.

Comment: Right, I suppose counter-example is the wrong term for it.  Let me edit.

Comment: Basically, you are asking: "show the conditions for the IFT are not necessary, only sufficient."

Comment: Yes... it seems that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=x-y^3$ is a basic case.  It's partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=3y^2$ is zero at $(x,y)=0$, but the function has a local inverse there.

The implicit function theorem is a generalization of the case when $m=0,n=1$, where, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and $f'(a)\neq 0$, then $f$ is $1-1$ on some neighborhood of $a$. Then  $f(x)=x^3$ is an example where $f'(0)=0$ but $f$ is still $1-1$ on all of $\mathbb R$, and hence a neighborhood of $0$.

So the implicit function theorem is not meant to be necessary. The "problem points" are spotted with differentiation, but you can easily find examples where the problem points still don't break the local inverse.

Comment: I see the idea now, thanks! Also, you probably meant $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -3y^2?$ Because as written, $\partial_x f = 1.$

Comment: Yeah, got it backwards. @Merkh

Comment: But the local inverse of the function $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ does not have a derivative at (0,0). So this is not a counterexample to the converse IFT.